# Update State when element of ForEach is updated without using Index

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following simple ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var matrix = [BoxModel(id: 0), BoxModel(id: 1), BoxModel(id: 2)]
@State private var chosen = BoxModel(id: -1)

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {

                    let columns = [GridItem(.fixed(50), spacing: 0),
                                     GridItem(.fixed(50), spacing: 0),
                                     GridItem(.fixed(50), spacing: 0)]
                    

                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0 ) {
                        ForEach(matrix) { box in
                            Button {
                                chosen = box
                            } label: {
                                Text("\(box.number)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    Button {
                        chosen.number = 5
                    } label: {
                        Text("Click Me")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

where the BoxModel is an object like this:

```
struct BoxModel: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var number: Int
}
```

When the button is pressed I want the "box" to be updated with the new number. But I want to do this without using the index. I know that if I get the index of the box, I can do something like matrix[0].number = 5 and it'll work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows boxes that are contained in the `matrix` array, while you have also created `chosen` which is a completely different instance.

You change `chosen` to store 5 in the "number" property, and I bet it's changing, but you are still only showing in the UI the instances of the boxes that are inside the `matrix` array, whatever happens to `chosen` will not be seen on the screen.

You need to completely drop the `chosen` variable, and have a button that changes each *instance* of "box" that is in the `matrix`. You might want to move your code inside the `ForEach` to another view too; that view would have a `@State` var of type `BoxModel` of its own, so you can see the changes as they happen.

Comment: Could you elaborate on moving the code to a different view? Do you have a small example?

Comment: You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299036/changing-button-label-and-title-dynamically-for-buttons-created-from-array-in-s/71299234#71299234). Look at the `StudentButton` view: it has its own `@State` property.

Comment: But how does the grid tell the button which square is tapped?